# Changing dropdown list/check box options

Tags: php, checkbox, dynamic-data, html-select, expert-system

I have 4 **drop-down lists / group of checkboxes** in I need that **after making a selection** in any one list the options available in the other 3 lists **change** accordingly...either are not available for selection or are not present in the list itself.

I'm coding using **PHP & MYSQL**
Could someone please help me with this. I'm new to PHP.

Comment: PHP is a server-sided programming language. *"After making a selection"* indicates that the drop-down list is already at the client-side. There is no way that PHP can make a change on the client-side, without help from a client-sided programming language such as javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with just PHP and MySQL.  You need to use Javascript or jQuery.  jQuery is the easiest to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but very hard. You should use jQuery, it's easier than PHP.